# JMS-bridge configuration not sharing a load on both hornetQ server

Tags: jms, load-balancing, hornetq, wildfly-9

I have tried to configure HornetQ server-side load-balancing using JMS bridge. I am using Wildfly 9, and I have done following configuration on `standalone-ha.xml` file but it is not sharing load between two server. Server running properly but message goes on only one instance.

```xml
<jms-bridge name="myBridge">
    <source>
        <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory"/>
        <destination name="jms/queue/MyQueue"/>
    </source>
    <target>
        <connection-factory name="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
        <destination name="jms/queue/MyQueue"/>
        <context>
            <property key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory"/>
            <property key="java.naming.provider.url" value="http-remoting://192.168.102.33:9090"/>
        </context>
    </target>
    <quality-of-service>AT_MOST_ONCE</quality-of-service>
    <failure-retry-interval>1000</failure-retry-interval>
    <max-retries>-1</max-retries>
    <max-batch-size>2</max-batch-size>
    <max-batch-time>100</max-batch-time>
    <add-messageID-in-header>true</add-messageID-in-header>
</jms-bridge>
```

I have read JBoss article for the same but it is not give proper solution for problem. Any one suggest what is the issue here? How can we solve this issue please suggest?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other folks who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A JMS bridge is a simple mechanism to move messages from a "source" to a "destination". It has nothing to do with server-side load-balancing. If you want server-side load-balancing you need to configure clustering.